# How to execute code when stopping application from debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When running an application, the application start many secondary processes that run on their own. When the app close those process are stopped.

My problem is that the only place i could figure out that work is using the `Application.ApplicationExit` event. It works when running the app and even when it crashes but the problem is when debugging with Visual Studio if you stop the code it doesn't trigger that code and we have couple hundreds of processes to kill.

I am looking for a better way than writing a batch file and list all processes to kill that i have to run every time a dev stop the code from running from within visual studio.

Maybe there is another event that is triggered when an app that is stopped by visual studio that i missed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your child processes to always be killed when the parent is terminated, you could consider using a Job Object to associate them all.  As each child process is started, add it to the job object shared by the parent; when the parent is terminated, Windows will also terminate all of the processes associated with that job object.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. At least not with external process like notepad. The `CreateJobObject` gets a proper handle and the `AssignProcessToJobObject` does not crash but when closing the console app notepad unfortunately stays open despite the doc saying otherwise.